# Timer stops app

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have a `timer`. But when I make for example a `toast` inside the `timer` the app crashes. But when I only increase a variable the timer works.

Here is my code:

```
package com.dev.moritz.colora;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class gameActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        startGame();
    }

public void startGame() {
        Timer ballMovement = new Timer();
        ballMovement.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, 0, 5000);
    }

}
```

I hope anyone can help me.
Moritz

Comment: Please post error log

Comment: Your logcat, when your app crashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:**
Any task running on Non-UI thread, cannot interact with the UI.

So, when you want to update UI from Timer Task, one way of the way is to use [`runOnUiThread()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) that comes from [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class, put that piece of code using inside your [`TimerTask's`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) `run()` method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(gameActivity.this, "Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

And it will work as expected.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Timer class blocks MainThread' and 'cannot work with or interact with UI Thread'? The whole idea of a timer is that it does not block the thread it was created on. And surely you can interact with a main thread from another thread, using a `Handler`. It is not allowed to do UI related work on a non-main thread, like a `Timer`'s callback

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Yes You can interact with UI using runOnUiThread or using Message and Handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void startGame() {
    Timer ballMovement = new Timer();
    ballMovement.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with **runOnUiThread** ,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

This is an option that you can try.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   private Handler updateUI = new Handler() {
       @Override
      public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
           super.dispatchMessage(msg);
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "142", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   };
   public void run() {
       try {
           updateUI.sendEmptyMessage(0);
       } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
   }
}, 0, 5000); // time in milliseconds
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried at my end and here it is working fine:

You must have got RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

To overcome above issue change your method to:

```
public void startGame() {
    Timer ballMovement = new Timer();
    ballMovement.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
}
```